# Figuring out which one (if any) to delete as duplicates

Tags: discussion, specific-question

So, I was viewing the current questions and I noticed an item on the sidebar that looked very familiar. Pursuing it, and doing a quick search, it looks like we have three `Story Identification` questions for *Black and Blue Magic*:

- [Kids Story Question: Ointment gives kid wings, loses them when seen](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36782/kids-story-question-ointment-gives-kid-wings-loses-them-when-seen?rq=1)
- [Name of Young Adult novel from 1960s/ 70s with Harry Houdini?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/46662/name-of-young-adult-novel-from-1960s-70s-with-harry-houdini)
- [YA novel where clumsy boy gains wings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52001/ya-novel-where-clumsy-boy-gains-wings/52013#52013)

The first two are relatively brief questions, and both contain small bits of incorrect information (one stating that Houdini was the boy's benefactor and the other saying it was his uncle, when in fact it was one of the residents at his mother's boarding house), so I'm inclined to mark them as Dupes of the third, but I also have the accepted answer on that one, so I didn't want to act too boldly for fear of being accused of trying to hide the other two questions in favor of the one I answered.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's perfectly fine to mark questions 1 and 2 as duplicates in favor of question 3, even if yours is the accepted answer for question 3. If question 3 truly contains the most accurate information, I would think that trumps the order in which the questions were posed.